# How do I bind the hashmap key and value to a recycler view?

Tags: android-recyclerview, hashmap

I am using a hashmap to collect items added to cart. So the key is the chosen item and the value is the quantity.

Using an interface I can send my hashmap to the adapter for the cart recyclerview but I dont know how to extract the key and value to show the item and quantity respectively.

I tried converting the hashmap into an array

```
for (Object name: selectionItemsHashMap.keySet()){
            String key = (String) name;
            int value = (int) selectionItemsHashMap.get(name);
            Log.d(TAG, "converting string menu item name:" + key);
            Log.d(TAG, "converting int menu item quantity:" + value);
            SelectionItem selectionItem = new SelectionItem( key, value);
            selectionItemArrayList.add(selectionItem);
        }
```

But this does not work. I end up something like this:

Item 1: Qty 1
Item 1: Qty 2
Item 1: Qty 3

instead of 
Item 1: Qty 3

Here is my onClick from the shop section:

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    String itemNameCheck = menuItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName();
                    if (selectionItemsHashMap != null && selectionItemsHashMap.containsKey(itemNameCheck)) {
                        int currentQuantity = selectionItemsHashMap.get(itemNameCheck);
                        currentQuantity++;
                        selectionItemsHashMap.put(itemNameCheck,currentQuantity);

                    } else {
                        selectionItemsHashMap.put(menuItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName(), 1);

                    }
                    totalAmount += Integer.parseInt(tvMenuItemPrice.getText().toString());
                    amountAddListener.onAmountAdd(totalAmount, selectionItemsHashMap);
```

And my onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.tvSelectItem.setText("how do I get my hashmap key here?");
        String quantity = Integer.toString("how do I get my hashmap value for the above key here?");
        viewHolder.tvDishQuantity.setText(quantity);
    }
```

Comment: Since `selectionItemsHashMap` only contains the key value pair, so can you explain about the order in which you want to show the items in RecyclerView?

Comment: @GB, I just want to the key which is a product e.g. Item 1 and the quantity which is 'n' in a recycler view. So each view holder will show the product followed by the selected quantity.

Comment: does the order in which products are shown matter?

Comment: @GB no that does not matter.

Comment: You can try using `LinkedHashMap` in which order will be maintained and based on the position, you can populate the corresponding values in `onBindViewHolder` method.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the data from the map to an array using foreach statement.